# Class assignment requires me to have two versions of the same code. This one, and one using BigInteger. Need help converting to BigInteger

Tags: java, string, long-integer, biginteger

1. I am required specifically to use BigInteger in place of long. This is so if the fibonacci number is too large, it won't return a negative. We haven't done some of the more complicated functions that java has built in, so I'm going to have to do it as simple as possible.

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class FibBigInt{


       public static long fib_l(int n){

           long result = 0;
           long f0 = 1, f1 = 1;

           while(n > 0){

               f0 = f1;
               f1 = result;
               result = f0 + f1;

               n--;
           }
           return result;
       }

       public static long fib_r(int n){
           long result = 1;

           if(n <= 2){

               return result;

           }
           else{

               result = fib_r(n - 1) + fib_r(n - 2);

           }

           return result;
       }

       public static long fval[];

       public static long fib_r_Memo(int n){

           long result = 1;

           if(n > 2) {

               if(fval[n] != 0){

                   result = fval[n];
               }
               else{

               result = fib_r_Memo(n - 1) + fib_r_Memo(n - 2);

               fval[n] = result;

               }
           }
           return result;
       }


       public static void main(String [] args){

           Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

           System.out.print("Please enter an integer: ");

           int n = s.nextInt();

           long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();

           //System.out.println("Fibonacci number " + n + " is " + fib_l(n));

           //System.out.println("Fibonacci number " + n + " is " + fib_r(n));


           fval = new long[n + 1];

           for(int i = 0; i < fval.length; ++i){

               fval[i] = 0;

           }

           System.out.println("Fibonacci number " + n + " is " + fib_r_Memo(n));

           long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();

           System.out.println("Elapsed time: " + (t2 - t1)/1000 + " seconds. ");

       }

   }
   ```

Comment: There is no point converting the recursive version.  Any solution which needs BigInteger won't complete in your life time anyway ;) i.e. the run time is proportional to the answer which grows O(e^N)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Actually, if you use a [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) optimization the recursive version is just as fast as the iterative.

Comment: Thats why its memoized. Plus, I kinda have to convert it. :/

Comment: You can also use memorization for the iterative version. You could use a List instead of an array to make it easier to add values. To make it faster you can calculate the first say 1000 values to warm up the code on start up ;)

Comment: BTW for really large values, it can take more time to toString() than calculate them ;) You could cache their toString() as well.

Comment: I guess all this is a little out of my league.....

Comment: @PeterLawrey If you need it *really* fast you use [Binet's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example recursive `BigInteger` version using a [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) optimization and supporting the "[negafibonacci](http://research.allacademic.com/meta/p_mla_apa_research_citation/2/0/6/8/4/p206842_index.html)",

```
private static Map<Integer, BigInteger> memo = new TreeMap<>();
private static final BigInteger NEGATIVE_ONE = new BigInteger("-1");

public static BigInteger fib(final int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        // This if block adds the "negafibonacci" support.
        final int p = Math.abs(n);
        final boolean even = p % 2 == 0;
        if (even) {
            return NEGATIVE_ONE.multiply(fib(p));
        }
        return fib(p);
    } else if (n == 0) {
        return BigInteger.ZERO;
    } else if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
        return BigInteger.ONE;
    }
    if (memo.containsKey(n)) {
        return memo.get(n);
    }
    BigInteger r = fib(n - 1).add(fib(n - 2));
    memo.put(n, r);
    return r;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = -8; i <= 8; i++) {
        System.out.println(fib(i).toString());
    }
}
```

When I run the above I get a sequence that matches the one from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) -

> ```
> −21   13  −8  5   −3  2   −1  1   0   1   1   2   3   5   8   13  21
> ```

Finally, I created a simple benchmark -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
        System.out.println(fib(i));
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.printf("Ran in: %d milliseconds", end - current);
}
```

When I calculate the first 999 fibonacci numbers it completes in under 200 milliseconds. If you really wanted to optimize further you could look into the [Closed-form Expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression).

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this answer is way out of my skill level. :/

Comment: @Historiun Try to re-read the answer starting at `if (n == 0) {` and stopping at the end of `fib(int)`. Finally, it's important to note that `BigInteger` is not modified in place when you call methods on it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still lost. I appreciate your help though regardless

Comment: The problem is, this is an assignment for class. We have to turn in two versions. This one, and a BigInteger version. Some of the things you used in your code have not even been discussed yet in class. So I'm not sure how to use them

Comment: @Historiun Probably a good idea to update your question to indicate it's for a class, and to tell us what you can and cannot use. Are you confused by the [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)? I prefer that to an array for the memoization. Java arrays are statically sized.

Comment: I changed the question to, hopefully, explain a bit better